# JOGL failure; whatever I do is black screen. Shaders malfunctioning, glGetAttribLocation returns -1

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I have a JOGL failure. I simply can't make it display anything. I've made Android OpenGL ES work, but I have 2 big problems here. First, nothing displays. Second, none of my variables exist for the shader compiler.

I am sorry that this is not a SSCEE. I just have this stinky bug and I can't reproduce it with shorter code.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.jogamp.opengl.GL2;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLEventListener;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import com.leonidnediak.labyrinth.annoyingGLstuff.ShaderStuff;
import com.leonidnediak.labyrinth.util.FileUtil;

public class Main implements GLEventListener {

public static File codeSource;

static {
    try {
        codeSource = new File(Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

    }
}

public static final Dimension size = new Dimension(400, 600);



public static int program;
public static int aColorLocation;
public static int aPositionLocation;
public static int uMatrixLocation;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
    GLCapabilities cap = new GLCapabilities(profile);

    GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(cap);
    canvas.addGLEventListener(new Main());
    canvas.setSize(size);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(size);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.add(canvas);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

@Override
public void display(GLAutoDrawable autoDrawable) {
    GL2 gl = autoDrawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);
    FloatBuffer vertexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*9).asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(new float[] {-1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0});
    vertexBuffer.position(0);
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, 3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, false, 12, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aColorLocation);
    FloatBuffer colorBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*9).asFloatBuffer();
    colorBuffer.put(new float[] {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1});
    colorBuffer.position(0);
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, 3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, false, 12, colorBuffer);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

@Override
public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable autoDrawable) {

}

@Override
public void init(GLAutoDrawable autoDrawable) {
    GL2 gl = autoDrawable.getGL().getGL2();
    program = ShaderStuff.buildProgram(gl, FileUtil.fileContents(new File(codeSource, "vertexShader.glsl")), FileUtil.fileContents(new File(codeSource, "fragmentShader.glsl")));
    int[] arr = new int[1];
    gl.glGetProgramiv(program, GL2.GL_ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES, arr, 0);
    System.out.println(arr[0]);
    aColorLocation = gl.glGetAttribLocation(program, "a_Color");
    aPositionLocation = gl.glGetAttribLocation(program, "a_Position");
    uMatrixLocation = gl.glGetUniformLocation(program, "u_Matrix");
    System.out.println(program);
    gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(uMatrixLocation, 1, false, new float[] {1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1}, 0);
}

@Override
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {

}

}
```

sorry for indentation, stackoverflow forces me to indent a lot.
That's my Main class.
Here's my ShaderStuff:

```
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL2;

public class ShaderStuff {

public static int compileVertexShader(GL2 gl, String shaderCode) {
    return compileShader(gl, GL2.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, shaderCode);
}

public static int compileFragmentShader(GL2 gl, String shaderCode) {
    return compileShader(gl, GL2.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, shaderCode);
}

private static int compileShader(GL2 gl, int type, String shaderCode) {
    final int shaderObjectId = gl.glCreateShader(type);
    if (shaderObjectId == 0) {
        return 0;

    }
    gl.glShaderSource(shaderObjectId, 1, new String[] {shaderCode}, null);
    gl.glCompileShader(shaderObjectId);
    final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
    gl.glGetShaderiv(shaderObjectId, GL2.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);
    if (compileStatus[0] == 0) {
        //gl.glDeleteShader(shaderObjectId);
        //return 0;
    }
    return shaderObjectId;
}

public static int linkProgram(GL2 gl, int vertexShaderId, int fragmentShaderId) {
    final int programObjectId = gl.glCreateProgram();
    if (programObjectId == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    gl.glAttachShader(programObjectId, vertexShaderId);
    gl.glAttachShader(programObjectId, fragmentShaderId);
    gl.glLinkProgram(programObjectId);
    final int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
    gl.glGetProgramiv(programObjectId, GL2.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
    if (linkStatus[0] == 0) {
        //gl.glDeleteProgram(programObjectId);
        //return 0;
    }
    return programObjectId;
}

public static int buildProgram(GL2 gl, String vertexS, String fragS) {
    int program;
    int vertexShader = compileVertexShader(gl, vertexS);
    int fragmentShader = compileVertexShader(gl, fragS);
    program = linkProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    validateProgram(gl, program);
    return program;
}

public static boolean validateProgram(GL2 gl, int programObjectId) {
    gl.glValidateProgram(programObjectId);
    final int[] validateStatus = new int[1];
    gl.glGetProgramiv(programObjectId, GL2.GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, validateStatus, 0);
    return validateStatus[0] != 0;
}

}
```

EDIT: the problem is in my GLSL but I can't find my failure.

Vertex Shader:

```
attribute vec4 a_Color;
attribute vec4 a_Position;

uniform mat4 u_Matrix;

varying vec4 v_Color;

void main()
{
    v_Color = a_Color;
    gl_Position = u_Matrix * a_Position;
    gl_PointSize = 1.0;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 v_Color;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = v_Color;
}
```

Comment: where are your shaders and shader compilation/link log results? most likely you got bug in shader code which prevent linkage or optimized out variables  hence not found locations....

Comment: You query and check GL_COMPILE_STATUS and GL_LINK_STATUS but you don't do anything if one of these fails.

Comment: Also be aware of the GLSL version in your shaders according to the GL version of the context.

Comment: I just realized that I have an error in my GLSL, but I keep getting this error: 0:1(1): error: syntax error, unexpected NEW_IDENTIFIER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few observations/hints:

- keeps locations hierarchical, like [here](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/framework/Semantic.java), it's less error prone and keeps your code more readable:

  ```
  public class Semantic { // or Location

      public static class Attr {

          public static int POSITION = 0;
          public static int COLOR = 3;
      }
  }
  ```
- don't allocate a new `FloatBuffer` every frame in the `display()`, initialize it in the `init()` and reuse it. You can use one utility of mine to dispose it, I'll tell you later.
- Avoid reinventing the wheel, you could avoid your `ShaderStuff` class completely, use what jogl already provides us, [here](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/tests/es_200/Es_200_draw_elements.java#L94-L110) an example. it will automatically print out any compilation error.
- which GLES versione are you targetting? Becuase in the shaders `varying` is deprecated, use `in` and `out` instead
- same for `gl_FragColor`, use `out vec4 FragColor;`

We have others jogl users that is working in this direction, we could create a simple and clear hello triangle sample explicitely made for android, would that be interesting for you?

Comment: I just managed to fix the errors in my shaders. it didn't like precition mediump float. I was compiling the fragment shader as vertex shader lol